# Is there some text editor in Mac which has an embedded terminal window?

Tags: macos, terminal, gedit

I have seen that the linux version of gedit supports a plugin in which you get a terminal window at the bottom of the gedit screen. Is there some such equivalent for Mac?

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/292953/are-there-any-mac-text-editors-with-a-built-in-terminal